# Sending an SMS on new order placed - WooCommerce

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to send SMS while new order gets placed, now I have used `woocommerce_order_status_completed` hook, but this only works while you move order processing to complete.
Alternatively, I have also used `woocommerce_order_status_processing` but it's also not working.

So the question is can I send SMS at the same time while the order getting placed?
**Note: SMS are working fine here**

Answer (score 1):

Please try the `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` or `woocommerce_new_order`